# Cannot publish artifact 'xxx.aar' (xxx.aar) as it does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, maven-plugin

Could not publish configuration 'archives',Cannot publish artifact `danlu-bluetooth.aar` (`/Users/xxx/work/xxx/workplace/androidcode/libraray/xxx/bluetooth/xxx-bluetooth.aar`) as it does not exist.

Compile environment description：

1. gradle verison is 4.10.2
2. Android Gradle plugin version is 3.2.1

Maven Plugin configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
uploadArchives {
uploadArchives {
repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
        snapshotRepository(url: "${mvn.snapUrl}") {
            authentication(userName: "${mvn.name}", password: "${mvn.pass}")
        }

        repository(url: "${mvn.url}") {
            authentication(userName: "${mvn.name}", password: "${mvn.pass}")
        }

        pom.project {
            version getVersionName()
            artifactId getArtifactId()
            groupId "${mvn.groupId}"
            packaging "${mvn.packaging}"
            description getDesc()
        }
     }
 }


task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
artifacts {
   archives file(getArtifactId() + ".aar")
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

Error Log :

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Cannot publish artifact 'danlu-bluetooth.aar' (/Users/xxx/work/danlu/workplace/androidcode/libraray/xxx/bluetooth/danlu-bluetooth.aar) as it does not exist.
    at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.isValidToPublish(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:117)
    at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.addConfigurations(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.toPublishMetaData(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:83)
    at org.gradle.internal.component.external.ivypublish.DefaultArtifactPublisher.publish(DefaultArtifactPublisher.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyContextualArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyContextualArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyContextualArtifactPublisher.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:133)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:63)
    at
```

Comment: gradle version 4.1 and androd gradle plugin version 3.0.1 everthing is ok .  I guess it's Compatibility problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
artifacts {
   archives file(getArtifactId() + ".aar")
   archives sourcesJar
}
```

Just use 'archives sourcesJar'.